# Rails params not receiving variable passed from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller, rails-routing

I have defined a CRUD resource called `items`, which I've added a collection route to called `similar_items`.

In the `view/show`, I have: `link_to similar_items_items_path(), :similar_to => @item`

In my `similar_items` controller method, what's the best way to get the item that was passed from `link_to`? The params hash does not contain `similar_to` which I've clearly passed as shown above. Why is it not being passed into params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass parameters inside the path helper:

```
link_to 'Your link label here', similar_items_items_path(:similar_to => @item)
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, for this, would it be better to have `similar_items` as a collection or a member?

Comment: @Darksky if you are defining a route to show similar items for one  item, it's better to define it as a member's route.